# How to filter data from locals based on condition terraform?

Tags: json, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl, hashicorp

**Main.tf**

```
locals {
    location_mapping = [
    {
        "location": "L1"
        "resource_group_name": "R1"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W1"
    },
    {
        "location": "L2"
        "resource_group_name": "R2"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W2"
    },
    {
        "location": "L3"
        "resource_group_name": "R3"
        "name_log_workspace_name": "W3"
    }
    ]
}

data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
    # Populate name and resource group based on var.location(L2) condition if location matches in locals
    name                = "W2"
    resource_group_name = "R2"
}
```

I want to populate **name** and **resource_group_name** dynamically based on the location condition in data block from locals.

**Example**

if I pass `location value L2` then `name=W2` and `resource_group_name=R2`

Comment: Could you restructure your input data so you have a map of locations to names and resource names? If so that makes it pretty simple to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can re-organize your `local.location_mapping` into mapping, e.g., called `local.helper_map`:

```
locals {
      helper_map = {for val in local.location_mapping:
                    val["location"]=>val}
}
```

Then in your `azurerm_log_analytics_workspace` you can use it as follows:

```
data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
    # Populate name and resource group based on var.location(L2) condition if location matches in locals
    name                = local.helper_map["L2"]["name_log_workspace_name"]
    resource_group_name = local.helper_map["L2"]["resource_group_name"]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin you mean to say 2 local blocks one for location_mapping data and other for helper_map.

Comment: @NaveenKumar You can use one, for both variables.

Comment: Hi @Marcin what if i want to match 2 conditions like `location is L2` and `resource_group_name is R2`